# How can transform UIViewController frame in a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

This is my ViewController and i have added 5 view controller(First, second, third...) in a UIScrollView. But now i want uiscrollview to transform 2 viewcontrollers per page to 1 viewcontroller per page with animation on a button(Single View) click and other controllers move to forward with appropriate x-axis. Similarly again i want two controllers on a button(Double view) click event. Please any one guide me.

[image]

Comment: You can use CollectionView with ContainerView in cell, and load your appropriate controller in each cell.

Comment: and when you want to show just one controller, resize your collection view cell, and with the right constraints your containerView will expand within.